# Converting Entity Framework Exceptions into HttpStatusCodes

Tags: c#, entity-framework, exception

I am looking for two things here:

I am looking for a list of possible exceptions that EF throws when there are issues. I thought [this post would give me what I want](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entityexception(v=vs.110).aspx), but it only shows the parent.

I secondly plan on converting these Exceptions to HttpStatusCodes that we can act on (display good messages to the user) for what happened.

```
catch (NotFoundException exception)
{
    return HttpStatusCode.NotFound;
}

catch (TimeoutException exception)
{
    return HttpStatusCode.RequestTimeout;
}
```

Is there a list of the exceptions available? 
Does Something like the exception converter exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's anything documented fully. But luckly, [EF is open source](https://entityframework.codeplex.com/), so you can simply download the solution and filter in your *Solution Explorer* on anything that ends with Exception.

It would look like this:

[image: Entity Framework with exception filter in VS]

I presume this will cover most of them.

If you do go through with the Exception2StatusCode, definitely make it available somewhere for others to use :)

Comment: Thanks this is perfect. I will definitely make the code available.